# Extracting values from array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to extract the three values in each sub array, but it doesnt seem to work. Is there something unusual about the object that is returned, or is my array extraction code incorrect?

```
#https://github.com/Nedomas/indicators
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'indicators'

my_data = Indicators::Data.new([1,2,3,4,3,2,4,6,1,2])
temp=my_data.calc(:type => :bb, :params => 2)
puts temp.inspect
temp.output.each do |x| puts "#{x[0]},#{x[1]},#{x[2]}" end
```

output

```
king@death-star ~/Desktop/_REPOS/misc/stock_analysis/forex/oanda/ruby $ ruby temp.rb 
#<Indicators::Main:0x00000002c1f9b0 @abbr="BB", @params=[2, 2], @output=[nil, [1.5, 2.914213562373095, 0.08578643762690485], [2.5, 3.914213562373095, 1.0857864376269049], [3.5, 4.914213562373095, 2.085786437626905], [3.5, 4.914213562373095, 2.085786437626905], [2.5, 3.914213562373095, 1.0857864376269049], [3.0, 5.82842712474619, 0.1715728752538097], [5.0, 7.82842712474619, 2.1715728752538097], [3.5, 10.571067811865476, -3.5710678118654755], [1.5, 2.914213562373095, 0.08578643762690485]]>
temp.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from temp.rb:9:in `each'
    from temp.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your output the first value of `output` variable is `nil`, you  can use [`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact):

> Returns a copy of self with all nil elements removed.

```
temp.output.compact.each do |x| 
   puts "#{x[0]},#{x[1]},#{x[2]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

First element of your array of array is `nil` and `nil` has no method `[]`. You can use `compact` method to remove `nil` elements.

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-compact